# Network UPS Tools (NUT) - Ubuntu 20.04 - Init SSL without certificate database Error: Data stale

Tags: 20.04, ssl, ups, nut

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04
**NUT**: 2.7.4-11ubuntu4 amd64

I have installed and configured the associated .conf files for a "Standalone" mode Network UPS Tools (NUT) driver/server/client using USB connector to UPS. The behavior I am experiencing is as follows:

1.) Initially when the applications are run (after a reboot), the upsmon (client) seems to be able to connect to the upsd (server) and access status information from the UPS. Example as follows:

```
upsc "my ups name"@localhost
 
Init SSL without certificate database

battery.charge: 100
battery.charge.warning: 30
battery.runtime: 2450
battery.type: PbAc
battery.voltage: 0.0
battery.voltage.nominal: 12.0
device.mfr: Tripp Lite
.....
```

2.) After some time period elapses, and I run the same command, the following occurs:

```
upsc "my ups name"@localhost
Init SSL without certificate database
Error: Data stale
```

My high level question is how do I fix this "Data stale" problem?  My lower level question is can I run this without SSL certificates (this is a Standalone implementation, so I am not concerned about "man-in-the-middle" issues with user/password in plain text going over the network).

I have already read the thread [nut (UPS) and SSL certificates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468632/nut-ups-and-ssl-certificates)  on this forum, but it is not directly related to the problem above.

Many thanks in advance for the forums help (I am a Noob).

I think I have established that the issue lies in the USBHID-UPS driver and this SSL certificate message is a "red herring" in terms of my issue.  The answer to my question lies somewhere in the driver interface as when I restart the driver (usbhid-ups) the issue resolves itself for an undetermined period of time and then fails again.

Further to this, if I stop/start the driver this "resets" the connection and then upsc command works until some time later when it shows `Init SSL without certificate database Error: Data stale`.

Commands to stop/start driver:

```
sudo /sbin/upsdrvctl stop
sudo /sbin/upsdrvctl start
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resides in USBHID-UPS driver failing periodically.  Once driver is restarted the problem goes away temporarily.  Will post another question regarding driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `MAXAGE 25` to `/etc/nut/upsd.conf` on the server, then restart the nut services or reboot the server. I just fixed this same issue about 20 minutes ago.